# invalidateOptionsMenu() deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, deprecated

In one of my fragment class, I using `invalidateOptionsMenu()` as below

```
invalidateOptionsMenu(activity)
```

but it is deprecated

> 'invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity!): Boolean' is deprecated. Deprecated
>   in Java

What can be used to replace `invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity activity)` ?

***P/S:This method still can be used, but will it be an issue in future?***

Comment: *but will it be an issue in future* - theoretically yes, but google does not exactly have a habit of actually removing deprecated apis so if you can't find the proper fix I wouldn't worry too much for now.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're deprecating this method in favor of calling `invalidateOptionsMenu` directly on the Activity (which this method actually does, internally). In order to replace it, you can do something like `requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()`.